# Сохранить значение массива объектов при повороте экрана

Tags: android

В общем, пробовал разные решения, форумы рекомендуют это.

Но при извлечении объекта ловлю

*Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$NonConfigurationInstances cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean[]*

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class testActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Boolean[] mAnswerBank = {null, null, null, null, null};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        mAnswerBank[0] = true;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mAnswerBank = (Boolean[]) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return mAnswerBank;
    }
}
```

Comment: Раз сохранили custom, то и восстанавливайте: `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`

Comment: Спасибо, добавьте, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий в ответ, чтобы я его отметил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@woesss:

Раз сохранили custom, то и восстанавливайте: `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`